# Cucumber JS: I get a "table.rows()" is not a valid function" error when I pass a table and one other variable to step def

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to validate values from a cucumber datatable to the front end. The test is working fine when I pass only the datatable to my step def but when I pass a variable along with the datatable; the test breaks and gives an error "**table.rows() is not a valid function**"

Here is my **feature file:**

Then the student info for student "1761" should be correct in the student list page

| Name| ID | Dept # |
| Monnie | 123| 1761|

**Step definition:**

```
Then(/^the student info for student "([^"]*)" should be correct in the fund list page$/, function (table, studNumber) {
let testTable = table.rows();
return this.pages.prd2Page.getCellInfo(studNumber).then((actualTexts) => {

return assert.deepEqual(testTable.toString(), actualTexts.toString());
//return console.log(actualTexts.toString());
});
});
```

As you can see, I am passing a datatable and a variable. If I remove the variable and hard code the value everywhere for the variable. This test passes. 
Could someone share some info as to what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify **all** variables you pass into the step definition.

Also, you need to consider the **order** of the parameters. The table is being passed at the end.

Example:

```
Then I order from "Dominos" a pizza for 4 ppl
  | Size  | Crust   |  Sauce  | Cheese     | 
  | 13.5  | Stuffed |  Tomato | Mozzarella |
```

Here you have (in order):

- pizza place name
- number of people
- data table

Definition is:

```
Then(/^I order from "(.*)" a pizza for (\d) ppl$/, function (pizza_place, ppl_num, table) {
  console.log('Buy from: ' + pizza_place);
  console.log('For ' + ppl_num + ' people');

  const input = table.hashes()
  console.log('Size: ' + input[0].Size);
  console.log('Crust: ' + input[0].Crust);
  console.log('Sauce: ' + input[0].Sauce);
  console.log('Cheese: ' + input[0].Cheese);
});
```

The output would be:

```
Buy from: Dominos
For 4 people
Size: 13.5
Crust: Stuffed
Sauce: Tomato
Cheese: Mozzarella
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you want to achieve with this step (step may sound silly, it is just a test):

```
Then I should see these in Missing required fields popup "test"
            | fieldName    |
            | Category     |
```

Auto generated step definition is:

```
Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)" these in Missing required fields popup$/, function(arg1, callback) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  callback(null, 'pending');
});
```

It seems like it is not possible to pass a parameter and a table at the same time. Instead, you can pass stdNumber to getCellInfo function using the values in table:

```
    Then(/^the student info for student "([^"]*)" should be correct in the fund list page$/, function (table, studNumber) {
      table.rows().forEach(row => {
          return this.pages.prd2Page.getCellInfo(row[2]).then((actualTexts) => {
            return assert.deepEqual(row.toString(), actualTexts.toString());
            //return console.log(actualTexts.toString());
            });
          });

      });
    }
```

cucumber [help](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/data_table_interface.md) also explains alternative usages.

note: my example is in typescript